# How to download all the required JARS to use play framework properly?

Tags: java, playframework

These last 2 days, I was trying to get a hold of the play framework (Java) but I had some issues to import some libraries to the project, for example the play.db.ebeans.model. Is there a way to automatically download and use these dependencies in intelliJ ?

Comment: You can use Maven to manage all dependencies for Play behind the scenes.  Have a look [here](https://www.playframework.com/modules/maven-1.0/home) for more information.

Comment: *Of course* the required JARs are required, but that isn't your question, is it?

Comment: My question is, if it is possible to configure these like maven dependencies , which it looks like you can :) thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Ebean in 2.4 is described! (in previous Paly 2.x it;s enabled by default)

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean

Answer (score 0):

If you updated build.sbt according to Play user guide (as mentioned here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean) and nothing changes then...

In case of IntelliJ 14.1.x I've noticed different behaviour during build.sbt file update. Sometimes after added new dependency my project is not reloaded automatically by IntelliJ and there is no fresh downloaded jars. So I have to find SBT toolbar (right side of IntelliJ window) and click "Refresh all SBT projects" icon to manually refresh all dependencies. 
13.x version of IntelliJ didn't have such problems for me.